# Center a span vertically inside an inline-block element

Tags: css

I have an `a` element which has a css rule : `display: inline-block;` (this css rules should not be changed), and inside this `a` element I have a span which I want to center vertically, and I want the height of the `span` element to be equal to the height of it's content.

```
<a class="anchor" href="#">
  Fonctionnalite 2
  <span class="label">Lecture</span>
</a>
```

This is what I tried :

```
.anchor {
    background: #38bcfc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999999;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 4px 0 1px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #FFF;
}
.label{
      float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    background-color: #abbac3!important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And this is a demo in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d3zyfv86/1/

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I'd say the best for vertical centering is to use flexbox, but that disregards your requirements.

Comment: in your fiddle your span is already centered and has the height of its parent

Comment: Looks centered to me?

Comment: Same here. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I think it does make sense, the OP wants the span to shrink to the height of the text, not to have 100% of the anchor height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the label to have height of its content, you have to set its `line-height` because currently it inherits from the anchor.

Additionally, you need to create a container for the text to position it vertically. So, I now use your label as a container and have another span as `label-text`.

The fix might be: https://jsfiddle.net/d3zyfv86/3/

Answer (score -2):

The question doesnt make much sence

but if you update the height of the span to 1.5em so then you can center it by removing `float: right` and adding `vertical-align: center` https://jsfiddle.net/d3zyfv86/2/